# compare two columns in the same text file

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have one textfile that have 12 columns and about 68000 lines.

I want to compare the two columns 2 and 12 to follow the condition if column2 <= column12 then put the whole line or row in a new textfile.
Or if column2 > column12 then delete the whole line or row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to learn some `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numpy

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt("filename.txt")
np.savetxt("new_filename.txt",data[data[:,1]==data[:,11],:])
```

You can also pass a delimiter as an argument to the functions `np.loadtxt("filename.txt", delimiter=",")`, comma in this case. The same works for `savetxt`

Have fun,
Cheers

Comment: The new_filename.txt is empty because you save the rows which have values of column1=column11 and there is not. But, I want to get the rows which following the condition column1=<column11. I change the sign == in savetxt to =< but it is invalid.

Comment: Try `<=`, because `=<` is not a valid conditional operator.

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working now. In the case I have some string columns in the file I read it with np.genfromtxt and put dtype=object and added fmt='%s' to np.savetxt but this gave different results from reading the file as float. What is the mistake?